# How the Dict work in Python? Is it a static member in class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to convert data in .csv file to dict with Python, I was faced with these problems. I run in Python3.4 and Win7. This is my main.py:

```
import csv

class user(object):
    user_id = ""  # User's ID
    number_to_item_info = {} # Mapping from int to list (contains a dict)
    def __init__(self, user_id, number, category):
        self.user_id = user_id
        if number in self.number_to_item_info:
            self.number_to_item_info[number].append([category])
        else:
            self.number_to_item_info.setdefault(number, [[category], ])

users_group = []

with open('test.csv', newline='\n') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        # print(row)
        User = user(row[0], row[1], row[2])
        if 'number' in User.number_to_item:
            users_group.append(User)
    User.number_to_item.clear() # Actually I really want to know this sentence

for user in users_group:
    print(user.user_id, user.number_to_item_info)
```

In my test.csv, the data is (for example):

```
['user_id', 'number', 'category']
['122333', '1', '1231234']
['333221', '1', '2211222']
['112233', '2', '2223444']
```

When I run it in Powershell(sorry), I get these results:

```
user_id {'number': [['category']]}
122333 {'1': [['1231234']]}
333221 {'1': [['2211222']]}
112233 {'2': [['2223444']]}
```

However, after I delete "User.number_to_item.clear()", I will get more information I don't want in dict.

The question is: If I delete that sentence, I will get extra repeated keys and values in dict in every member's dict; if I don't delete that sentence, I will get nothing in users_group's dict except user_id, it is right for every member.
I guess dict is **Static Class memeber** in Python, is that right? Or maybe I'm wrong? And How can I solve this issue?

P.S: The data and some codes is not complete since I modified it. If there are problems, please point it out. Thanks.

Comment: In case this helps you, here is a rather in depth article on Python's `Dict` implementation: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class user(object):
    number_to_item_info = {} # Mapping from int to list (contains a dict)
```

The above code creates `number_to_item_info` as a class attribute. It sounds like you want it to be an instance attribute. In that case, move the creation of `number_to_item_info` into the `__init__()` method:

```
class user(object):
    def __init__(self, user_id, number, category):
        self.number_to_item_info = {} # Mapping from int to list (contains a dict)
```

Reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Ahh the `dict` literal, there it is :)

Comment: In that case, may I suggest that you immediately stop whatever you are working on and complete the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/). Learning the language correctly the first time will prevent a lot of misconceptions later on.